# How to create a editable dropdownbutton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new  to flutter and am practicing using drop down button. So I made a basic app which allows you to create new string values and store then on the cloud and then populate the dropdownbutton with the values. I want to add a functionality that we can edit the member of the dropdropmenu item by long pressing it.

This is my drop down menu button

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _fireStore.collection("items").orderBy("value").snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshots) {
                    if (!snapshots.hasData) {
                      CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    return DropdownButton(
                      items: itemList,
                      value: dropDownValue,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropDownValue = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

This is the drop down menu item

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> itemList = [];
  String dropDownValue;


void getList() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _fireStore.collection("items").snapshots()) {
      itemList.clear();
      for (var message in snapshot.documents) {
        itemList.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          value: message.data["value"].toString(),
          child: Text(
            message.data["value"],
          ),
        ));

      }
    }
  }
```

I couldn't find any other solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your items each in a GestureDetector and pass a function to the LongPress() callback to update the cloud data.

Comment: Thanks!! I wrapped the text widget in the MenuItems in a gesture detector and it works.